# .net core Input tag helper does not appear to be rendering correctly

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an issue where a .net core input tag helper does not appear to be rendering correctly.

```
<input id="FullName" type="text" class="standard-textbox" asp-for="Contact.FullName" data-validation-required="@Html.Raw(Contact.FullNameValidationErrorMessage.Trim())" placeholder="@Contact.FullNameLabel.Trim()" required />
```

This is being rendered as:

```
<input id="FullName" type="text" class="standard-textbox" asp-for="Contact.FullName" data-validation-required="Please enter your name so we know who we're talking to." placeholder="Your full name" required="" aria-required="true" aria-describedby="FullName-error">
```

You will note the asp-for helper is not being re-rendered as a "name" attribute.

On another site, which uses essentially the same form, the input field is rendered correctly with asp-for being changed to name.

Comment: Did you include the `AspNetCore.Razor.Tools` package in your project.json file?

Comment: Yes (well I am on 1.1 and VS2017 so it no longer project.json but its referenced in the solution).   I even uninstalled and reinstalled the package but no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out!

The *Views/_ViewImports.cshtml* file was missing the following line:

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

Adding this line to the file fixed this issue.

Comment: 5-years later and 5-hours of head banging, and this was my issue. Thanks!